# .NET 4.5 WCF hosted on IIS unmanaged memory usage

Tags: .net, memory-management, red-gate-ants

I'm trying to profile memory usage in simple WCF service hosted on IIS. 
It seems strange to me - fairly large unmanaged memory consumption:

[image: ANTS Memory Profiler Screenshot]
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryo3B.png)

As you can see there is ~180MB memory used by unmanaged code/objects.
In detailed view I can see something like this:
[image: detailed view]
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp33G.png)

[image: detailed view 2]
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOy45.png)

RuntimeAssembly from System.Reflection namespace uses almost 80MB of memory. How is it possible? I'm not using any reflections in my code. Is it possible that this 80MB usage of System.Reflection is ANTS Memory Profiler stuff?

Please help me understand this - maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is ANTS. I'd say that the app being profiled is loading a whole lot of assemblies into an AppDomain dynamically at runtime. If you're not on the latest ANTS Memory Profiler, you may want to try that. It has a better ability to tie together managed and unmanaged memory use.